# When Query is executed, it displayed an error in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I created a table and added values to the table. While I was adding values in one of the field 'HomePhone', I gave data value as 'null'. After that, I executed the query its showed the error. Later, I decided to leave the data as blank by coding as ' '.

The error message displayed as

> "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated."

```
    /* Creating table6 Customer */
create table Customer
(
    CustomerID              int primary key identity(301,1) not null,
    AccountID               int not null,
    CustomerAddress1        varchar(30),
    CustomerAddress2        varchar(30),
    CustomerFirstName       varchar(30),
    CustomerMiddleInitial   char(1),
    CustomerLastName        varchar(30),
    City                    varchar(20),
    St_ate                  char(2),
    ZipCode                 char(10),
    EmailAddress            varchar(40),
    HomePhone               char(10),
    CellPhone               char(10),
    WorkPhone               char(10),
    SSN                     char(9),    
    UserLoginID             smallint not null
);
```

/* Adding 5 row values to table6 Customer */

```
insert into Customer(AccountID,CustomerAddress1,CustomerAddress2,CustomerFirstName,CustomerMiddleInitial,CustomerLastName,City,
                    St_ate,ZipCode,EmailAddress,HomePhone,CellPhone,WorkPhone,SSN,UserLoginID)
values
    (102,'456 DEF Street','Unit 12','Williams','Kevin','George','London','ON','M5D1B3','kevin@xyz.com',' ','3366991100','1234567890','456789012',2),
    (103,'789 PQR Street','Unit 20','Lindsay','Steffi','Davidson','Seattle','WA','98128','lindsay@xyz.com','6547893210','3366991100',' ','876543219',3);
```

I expect the query to be executed without error.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Because the string `'Kevin'` is longer than 1 character.  As is the string `'Steffi'`.

Comment: No where in your code did you explicitly provide a null value. You did provide a blank string - but that is VERY different from null.

Answer (score 1):

Error message clearly explains that **one of the value you are trying to insert is bigger than the length of column you have defined in your table.**

In your case you have defined `CustomerMiddleInitial`   as `char(1`), so you are not supposed to enter more than one character to this column value, but you are trying to insert following values.

```
Kevin
Steffi
```

Either alter the table to increase the column length or specify only one character to column `CustomerMiddleInitial`